# Statement of Economic Interests for website

Tags: california, conflict-of-interest, disclosure

I have purchased a Domain name and am planning to build a website for the domain name. I have not published a website yet. I have not received any funds for building the website or business. I also have not formed a business entity. I live and work in California. Here is my question:

I am employed by a government organization, so do I need to report this activity in Statement of Economic Interests?

Comment: Is there some reason that you believe you are required to file a Statement of Economic Interests?  This appears to be related to public officials who may have a conflict of interest.

Comment: @jwh20 I am employed by a government organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on one's particular circumstances, as merely being employed by a government organisation isn't enough on its own to warrant a Statement of Economic Interests (Form 700).

As an example of what those circumstances may be, this from LA County's [Board of Supervisors](https://bos.lacounty.gov/services/conflict-of-interest-lobbyist/statement-of-economic-interest/) stipulates that state and local government officials:

> publicly disclose their personal assets and income that may be **materially affected** by their official acts.

And agency employees, including some public officials who are designated in a conflict of interest code, are required to disclose:

> certain financial interests **according to the disclosure categories** assigned to that position in their agency's conflict of interest code.

And certain public officials, including public officials who manage public investments:

> are required to disclose **all financial interest.**